# Floating number regex between 0 and 1

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate input for floating number which max value is `1.0` and min value is `0`.

```
Min : 0
Max : 1
```

Possible values ;

```
0.1
0.99
0.365
```

how can i succeed it with regex?

Comment: Any reason why you are doing it with Regex? And even then, what have you tried?

Comment: Is scientific notation acceptable (1.2e-1)?  Is the leading zero required (e.g., is .123 okay)?  Is a sign okay (+0.5)?

Comment: tring to learn regex @Rohit

Comment: I don't know why you would solve a mathematical problem using string manipulation...

Comment: @tylerdurden.. Ok. Sure, but you can choose a better problem.

Comment: @RichardA. how is this an exclusively mathematical problem?

Comment: @RohitJain obviously but couldn't figure out this one.

Comment: @RohitJain most often the problems that puzzle you motivate you (to learn). As opposed to very small problems that you think you know how to solve and very big problems you know you're very far away from solving.

Comment: Is this validate (the string only contains the number and you want to check) or matching (finding the substring matching the regex)? The solution will be slightly different.

Comment: As you didn't specify clear enough in your question what you want and what you don't want (there are numerous ways to specify a number from 0.0 to 1.0), you get a bunch of answers that are slightly different from each other, which will more or less validates the number, but may allow or disallow some small cases of representation.

Comment: @nhahtdh right man, what i want is validate an input is a floating number 0 <= str and str <= 1

Comment: @tylerdurden: In different languages, there will usually be a way for you to parse floating point number. Use those to parse the number and then compare numerically.

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.  Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Comment: @AndyLester of course i know, I can do it in various way with c, c++  other languages. but the point is learning regex which i mentioned before. so focus the question and give an usefull example if you have one!

Comment: @tylerdurden If you're trying to learn regex (*or anything*), asking questions that really only have concrete, final answers won't help much. I think the read, try, fail, repeat until success method is more appropriate here; perhaps followed up with a question of "*I got X working, but why tried Y and it doesn't, why?*"

Comment: @Bracketworks right man, that's what i missed. I already tried lots of stuff but just didn't mention in the question. anyway you're right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As javascript regex literal:

```
 /^(0(\.\d+)?|1(\.0+)?)$/
```

Answer (score 6):

```
0(\.\d+)?|1\.0
```

The explanation:

```
0            # a zero
(\.\d+)?     # a dot and min 1 numeric digit - this is made optional by ?
|            # or
1\.0         # one, a dot and a zero
```

If you need this to match the whole sring then you will need the caret and the dollar signs that represent beginning of string and end of string, respectively like in `^(0(\.\d+)?|1\.0)$`

Also, if you want to look for possible negative numbers you will need to prepend an optional minus sign like in `^-?(0(\.\d+)?|1\.0)$`. For exponentials the pattern needs to change, of course.

Comment: I have also made the `.0` optional for `1`. Besides that, great solution.

Comment: Also matches negative values

Answer (score 3):

That's it:

```
/^(0+\.?|0*\.\d+|0*1(\.0*)?)$/
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm targeting on people who have difficulties with forming the expression but who can read and understand it themselves.

Comment: @NathanOliver, by the way, accepted answer has no any explanation either.

Comment: Your answer came up in the review queue.  It looked good so I just commented that it would be even better with an explanation.  I was not singling you out but just adding some constructive criticism.  You don't have to add anything if you do not want to.

Comment: This part `0*1\.?0*` of your regex matches `10000`

Answer (score 2):

This RegEx should do just fine:

```
/((0(\.[0-9]*)?)|(1(\.0)?))/
```

Unless you plan on matching exponential form floating points.

Comment: This will also match `1.9`.

Comment: does not match with boundaries?

Comment: Too many unnecessary stuff, and lacking the important anchors: `^(0\.\d*|1\.0)$` You also forgot `0` and `1`.

Comment: I'm not here to learn, tylerdurden is. He can figure out extra steps if he's trying to understand how this works.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: Just hope he tested the code. Actually there are many ways to specify a number from 0 to 1, even without exp. form. Slight change in the regex can allow or disallow some.

Comment: actually the first answer you did, is what i want.. this one doesnt match with the 0 or 1

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
0+([.][0-9]+)?|1([.]0)?
```

Or did I miss anything? :)

Answer (score 1):

This will match floats from [0,1] with an optional sign but will not match if scientific notation is used or the number starts with the decimal point.

```
\+?(0(\.[0-9]+)?|1(\.0+)?)
```

Comment: it matches with the bigger number than 1

Comment: It should not but I missed to include the first backslash and therefore the expression matched nothing at all. It will however match `111` as three times `1` unless you append something like `$`, `\s`, `[^0-9]` or something similar enforcing some kind of separation between multiple numbers.

Comment: It does not match `1.1` but it matches the first and second `1` separately. Similar with `2.0` - it matches `0`.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution:

`^0*(?:(?:0(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)|1(?:\.0*)?)$`

Formatted:

```
 ^     
 0* 
 (?:
      (?:
           0 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
   |  
      1 
      (?: \. 0* )?
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:(?<!\d*[1-9]\.?0*)(?:(?:0+(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+)|(?:1(?!\.0*[1-9]+)(?:\.0+)?)))$`

This will accept the numbers [0,1] in the following formats

`0 
0.5
.5
1
1.0
1.000`

Answer (score 0):

Just read a brief about regex.
Hope this works !

```
^(0.0*[1-9](\d+)?)$
```

Let me know if i am missing something.