# Regex for float numbers with two decimals in 0-1 range

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a HTML pattern / regex to allow only float numbers between 0 and 1 with maximum two decimals.

So, the following will be correct:

```
0
0.1
0.9
0.11
0.99
1
```

And these will be incorrect:

```
00
0.111
0.999
1.1
2
10
```

I have no knowledge of regex and I don't understand its syntax and I haven't found one online tool to generate a regex.

I've come with something from what I've gathered from online examples:

```
^(0[0-1]|\d)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

I have added `0[0-1]` to set a 0-1 range but it does not work. This regex matches every number between 0 and 9 that can also have maximum 2 decimals.

Comment: Check out this [site](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex

Comment: *"I have no knowledge of regex and I don't understand its syntax"* Don't use RegEx then.

Comment: [`^(?:0(?:\.\d{1,2})?|1(?:\.00?)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/wvzGb1/2). It is basically the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461945/floating-number-regex-between-0-and-1), but with limiting quantifiers.

Comment: What language are you programming with? The online manual for whatever language you are using will have information about regex usage in that language.

Comment: is `1.00` valid ? and `1.000` ?

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."* - Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) where the 0 part can be followed by an optional dot and 2 digits and the 1 part can be followed by an optional dot and 1 or 2 times a zero.

```
^(?:0(?:\.\d{1,2})?|1(?:\.0{1,2})?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `0(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match 0 and optionally a dot and 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `1(?:\.0{1,2})?` Match 1 and optionally a dot and 1-2 zeroes
- `)` Close group
- `$`  End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f1opdD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not ease with RegEx, you can use some code to check if the input corresponds with your needs, such as :

```js
function ValidateNumber(num)
{
  const floatNumber = Number(num);

  return floatNumber != NaN && 0 <= floatNumber && floatNumber <= 1 && ('' + num).length <= 4;
}

const TestArray = [ '42', 42, 0, '0', '1', '1.00', '1.01', '0.01', '0.99', '0.111', 'zero' ]
TestArray.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element + ' is ' + (ValidateNumber(element) ? '' : 'not ') + 'a valid number');
});
```